# How to clear the text after deleting a message

Tags: javascript, angularjs

having scenario like this.
i have list of comments to one post when i delete a comment that is deleting and getting success message.but here that is not removing until and unless refresh the page.

used `$route.reload()`
this is not solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: Update your `$scope.VAR`, can you add your code for more clarification. Don't have any clue for now.

Comment: The scope is certainly not updated. But without any code, it's very difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your comments array is `$scope.commentsArray=['comment 1', comment 2];`

By comment id or any identity that a particular comment have by which you can find out the index of that comment(which you want to delete) in array like this:

```
var a = $scope.commentsArray.indexOf("comment1");
```

After that Just splice this comment form your array and make a hard copy in the scope like this:

```
$scope.commentsArray = $scope.commentsArray.splice(index, 1);
```

after doing this  definitively changes will reflect on your view .. thanks it will help you

Answer (score 0):

If your comments are coming from server than you should call get request for your comments again after getting success from deleting your comment.

Hope this helps....